# python how to parse json file export from phpmyadmin

Tags: python, json, phpmyadmin

I have a json file exported from phpmyadmin, it looks like this(utf-8 file):

```
[{"user_email": "bh549@sina.cn","followee_id": 1411833182,"create_date": "cdatetime datetime p1 (S\'\\x07\\xdb\\x06\\x13\\x16\\x08(\\r\\xd5\\xcc\' tRp2 ."}, {"user_email": "zaici4@sina.cn","followee_id": 1296426000,"create_date": "cdatetime datetime p1 (S\'\\x07\\xdb\\x07\\x14\\x179\\x16\\x02 \\x08\' tRp2 ."}, {"user_email": "yanaa357@sina.com","followee_id": 1848085255,"create_date": "cdatetime datetime p1 (S\'\\x07\\xdb\\x08\\x13\\x17\\x10\\x0f\\x05\\x1c\\x02\' tRp2 ."}]
```

each dict is a row in database, and third value in each row is a cpickled string.

then I use form to upload this file to a python script (with post method).

then parse this file in python script like this:

```
   import cgi, os
    import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
    import json
    #import simplejson as json
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
    try:
        import msvcrt
        msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin = 0
        msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
    except ImportError:
        pass

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    file_content = form['mysql_table'].value
    file_content = json.loads(file_content)
```

then browser print a value error when execute json.loads:

`<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 83 (char 83)`

the char 83 is a space in third value in first row.

How to fix this problem?

thanks mhawke anyway.but the first problem you said is not exist. There's no \n because I copy that from print result, in my exported json file, it actually have \n

```
{"user_email": "bh549@sina.cn","followee_id": 1411833182,"create_date": "cdatetime
datetime
p1
(S\'\\x07\\xdb\\x06\\x13\\x16\\x08(\\r\\xd5\\xcc\'
tRp2
."}, {"user_email": "zaici4@sina.cn","followee_id": 1296426000,"create_date": "cdatetime
datetime
p1
(S\'\\x07\\xdb\\x07\\x14\\x179\\x16\\x02 \\x08\'
tRp2
."}
```

my be I misunderstand? second problem,It's phpmyadmin escape the file when export,then how to fix the problem you said?

**slouton:** I'm write a python script to export table and transform the pickled data. It worked now, seems now way to handle json with pickled data.

Comment: We need to see the *exact* problematic JSON.

Comment: [{"user_email": "bh549@sina.cn","followee_id": 1411833182,"create_date": "cdatetime datetime p1 (S\'\\x07\\xdb\\x06\\x13\\x16\\x08(\\r\\xd5\\xcc\' tRp2 ."}, {"user_email": "zaici4@sina.cn","followee_id": 1296426000,"create_date": "cdatetime datetime p1 (S\'\\x07\\xdb\\x07\\x14\\x179\\x16\\x02 \\x08\' tRp2 ."}, {"user_email": "yanaa357@sina.com","followee_id": 1848085255,"create_date": "cdatetime datetime p1 (S\'\\x07\\xdb\\x08\\x13\\x17\\x10\\x0f\\x05\\x1c\\x02\' tRp2 ."}]

Comment: @yayuan: it will be more readable and useful to update your question with the JSON input that causes the problem.

Comment: @mhawke: thank you for your hint, can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines are **not** valid in strings in JSON, and if phpMyAdmin is producing them then you should log a bug with the project.

```
>>> json.loads('"123"')
u'123'
>>> json.loads('"123\n456"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 4 (char 4)
```

Comment: thank you, seems can't using phpmyadmin to exprot json with pickled data. I'm using python to export the table and transform the pickled data in my script and work.

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't support hexadecimal escapes like `\x07`. You have to use unicode escapes instead (`\u0007`). Try converting one form into another before decoding:

```
content = content.replace('\\x', '\\u00')
```

Comment: I tried your method and the Value Error I mentioned still exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems.

The first is that the pickle seems to be invalid (I think). It is missing new line characters between the various components. e.g.

```
import cPickle
bad_pickle = "cdatetime datetime p1 (S\'\\x07\\xdb\\x06\\x13\\x16\\x08(\\r\\xd5\\xcc\' tRp2 ."
good_pickle = '\n'.join(bad_pickle.split())

>>> cPickle.loads(bad_pickle)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cPickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

>>> cPickle.loads(good_pickle)
datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 19, 22, 8, 40, 906700)
```

The second problem is that you need to escape the `\` escape with yet another `\`. You can easily do this using `replace`, e.g. `replace('\\', '\\\\')`

This code shows round trip JSON encoding and decoding including pickled objects:

```
import json, cPickle
from datetime import datetime

pickled_datetime = cPickle.dumps(datetime.now())
d = {"user_email": "bh549@sina.cn",
     "followee_id": 1411833182,
     "create_date": pickled_datetime }
j = json.dumps(d)

>>> d
{'create_date': "cdatetime\ndatetime\np1\n(S'\\x07\\xdc\\x06\\r\\x0c\\x16:\\x06/\\x85'\ntRp2\n.", 'followee_id': 1411833182, 'user_email': 'bh549@sina.cn'}
>>> j
'{"create_date": "cdatetime\\ndatetime\\np1\\n(S\'\\\\x07\\\\xdc\\\\x06\\\\r\\\\x0c\\\\x16:\\\\x06/\\\\x85\'\\ntRp2\\n.", "followee_id": 1411833182, "user_email": "bh549@sina.cn"}'
```

Notice how the backslashes in `j` have been escaped by an additional backslash. This is what the pickles coming from your database should look like. Decoding the JSON data stored in `j` is done like this:

```
d2 = json.loads(j)
cPickle.loads(d2['create_date'])

>>> d2
{'followee_id': 1411833182, 'create_date': "cdatetime\ndatetime\np1\n(S'\\x07\\xdc\\x06\\r\\x0c\\x16:\\x06/\\x85'\ntRp2\n.", 'user_email': 'bh549@sina.cn'}
>>> cPickle.loads(d2['create_date'])
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 13, 12, 22, 58, 405381)
```