# JSON Extract - Invalid Characters Found

Tags: json

I've exported a table from a MySQL database, choosing the JSON export option.

When I try to validate the file via an online formatter, I've found some problems with invalid characters. Extract of JSON file here: http://pastie.org/4149200.

I used http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate the file. The errors are occurring on product_desc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the line breaks inside your string value. Encode them as `\n`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Felix, now how would I encode those line breaks. The JSON output is directly from the MySQL table. I'm exporting it and selecting the JSON options and this is what I get.

Comment: I assume you are using phpMyadmin? Someone else had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991318/python-how-to-parse-json-file-export-from-phpmyadmin There does not seem to be a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks Felix, yes I'm using phpMyAdmin. I'll check out that link.

Comment: Felix, I wasn't able to fix the problem in the end but found a work around. I just exported the table using the SQL export option. Then imported it to my new database and wrote a script to take the records from one table to another. Not ideal bit worked anyway.

Comment: Just as a side note, I think there is something wrong with phpMyadmin if it is adding in /n for the JSON extract.